# Determine elapsed time in function?

Tags: python, timer, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ and Python to retrieve messages from the RabbitMQ server.  I would like the program to do something if more than 5 minutes have elapsed and no message was received from Rabbitmq.

I found the sample python code on the RabbitMQ website, and it runs and prints each message received.  I am trying to figure out how to add a timer so that I can do XYZ if more than 5 minutes have elapsed since a message was received.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?  Below is the code from RabbitMQ:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import time

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)        # Print out received message

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='SlackWebhook',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: I dont know about RabbitMQ, but lookin your code "BlockingConnection" my recomendation is take a look to a NonBlockingConnection because if they put blocking in the function name they must have a non blocking one. And then check time everitime that you call to the consumer.

Comment: A simple way to do it with a context manger is shown in the article [**_Timing Your Code Using Python's "with" Statement_**](http://preshing.com/20110924/timing-your-code-using-pythons-with-statement/). Just put the `channel.start_consuming()` line inside a `with Timer():`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Singleton object that is instantiated only once in your program. Inside this object, you can create a timer. You start the timer, keep it running, and reset it to zero each time receive something from RabbitMQ. Inside that Singleton, you need to have a `while True` loop that checks the timer and triggers some action if time elapsed is more than 5 minutes.

The basic idea is to have a timer running, setting it to zero each time you receive from RabbitMQ, and have an observer checking that timer for how much time has elapsed. The implementation can be with a Singleton, or any other data structure that will persist throughout your program. If you have multiple threads or processes, it'd be easier to use a persistent database or built-in thread-safe Python data structures.

Hope this helped.